# Python: how to get name of active render layer

Tags: python, scripting

Using Python, how do I get the name of the active render layer?

I have three render layers.  All three are enabled.  But only 1 can be "active." (highlighted in blue when I select it)

I would like to write a script that gets the active render layer name, appends it to the render Output filename, and only renders this layer.

Thank you.

Answer (score 3):

`bpy.context.scene.render.layers.active.name` gets the name of the active render layer.

Answer (score 3):

## Short Answer

Use the following snippet to get the active render layer's name

```
bpy.context.scene.render.layers.active.name
```

## Long Answer

Note: These steps build on each other; the complete code is shown at the end.

### 1. Get the scene

```
scene = bpy.data.scenes['SceneName']
```

- gets the scene "SceneName"

---

```
scene = bpy.data.scenes[0]
```

- gets the scene at index 0

---

```
scene = bpy.context.scene
```

- gets the current scene

### 2. Get the render layers

```
layers = scene.render.layers
```

- gets the render layers of the current scene (context.scene)

### 3. Get the active layer

```
active = layers.active
```

### 4. Get its name

```
name = active.name
```

---

### Summary:

```
scene = bpy.context.scene  # get the scene
layers = scene.render.layers  # get the list of layers
active = layers.active  # get the active layer from the list
name = active.name  # get the name of the active layer
```

Comment: Excellent.  Just what I was looking for.  Thank you

Comment: Isn't this just what I posted?

Comment: @RayMairlot The one liner is the same of course, but I felt it worth explaining just a bit more about how it came out. Your answer is *correct* (I up-voted it before I even wrote mine), but I don't think that it is very useful for those who want to understand it rather than just cut and paste :-)

Comment: I think if you felt it needed it expanding you should have commented that. If I see an answer that doesn't have enough information, I don't just generally post the same answer with slightly more detail.